# Authentication on SFDC Sites?

Tags: force.com-sites, customer-community, authentication, guest-user, spring21

We have a credit application form hosted on SFDC Sites.  A sales rep creates the credit app record, which triggers an email to be sent to the prospective customer.  A link in the email takes them to the application on the SFDC site.

As of the Spring '21 release (this Saturday), an unauthenticated site user won't be able to edit a record they don't own.  Since the credit app is owned by the sales rep, that's a problem.

Our current solution involves using Identity licenses, and having the customer log into our e-commerce site, on which they already have an account.  That site passes them over to SFDC, where we use JIT provisioning to create a user record and sign them in.  That's working fine, but only if we take the user into SFDC (to a Salesforce app).  We haven't been able to figure out how to trigger authentication by going to the SFDC site instead.

I see a lot of articles about doing this with partner communities, and I have a feeling this is similar, but that's about as far as we've been able to get.  Can someone point us in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: You want an External Identity license for your customers; this license is deployed in conjunction with a Community. Take a look at [Identity for Customers](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/identity_external/identity_external_community) Trailhead and [External Identity Impl Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.externalidentityImplGuide.meta/externalidentityImplGuide/external_identity_intro.htm)

Comment: Yep, that's what we have currently.  After the JIT class runs & the user is authenticated, the user can get to pages in the CRM, but the site still only recognizes him as a guest user.  Thinking that makes sense given that they're on different domains, but I'm not sure where to go from there -- how to authenticate into the site, rather than the CRM.  (I hope that makes sense!)

Comment: If you have a Community and you're authenticating correctly via a Community endpoint, that's all you need. From your description it's unclear where your implementation is faltering. Recommend you edit your question and provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)